# Mail in laravel , i want to send email with multiple recepients

Tags: php, laravel, oop, pdo, laravel-5

I have a problem here.. i try to send email to multiple recepients. The recepients are from my database which name of table is **subscribes** the message error is like this

> ```
> ErrorException in SimpleMessage.php line 297:
> Illegal offset type
> ```

```
public function store_job(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['posisi' => 'required','persyaratan' => 'required','tanggung_jawab' => 'required']);

        $tambah = new jobs(); //kita buat objek yang terhubung ke table JOBS
        $tambah->posisi = $request['posisi'];
        $tambah->persyaratan = $request['persyaratan'];
        $tambah->tanggung_jawab = $request['tanggung_jawab'];
        $tambah->kategori = $request['kategori'];
        $tambah->save();


        $anu = DB::table('subscribes')->select('email');
        $data = array ('email'=>$anu);
        Mail::send('emails.news', $data, function ($message) use ($request, $data) {
        $message->from('stevanajja@gmail.com',$request->email);     
        $message->to($data['email'])->subject($request->posisi);;
        });
        return redirect()->to('/panel_admin/opportune');
    }
```

please help as fast as possibble.. because i am a student, this is my homework for examination.

Comment: If this is your homework then you should do it. No need for asking us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what I'am doing is declaring a new array `$emails` to store all email from database. By iterating the retrieved object `anu`, I am pushing the email to `$emails` and passing it to the `to` property of the mail.

```
    $anu = DB::table('subscribes')->select('email')->get();
    $emails=[];
    foreach($anu as $a){
         $emails[]=$a->email;
    }
    Mail::send('emails.news', $emails, function ($message) use ($request, $emails) {
    $message->from('stevanajja@gmail.com',$request->email);     
    $message->to($emails)->subject($request->posisi);;
    });
```

Comment: btw thx jonju, but it still doesn't work.. another error ErrorException in CrudController.php line 58:
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: I think we missed `get()` method.Check now

Comment: i really thankyou for you Jonju.. God Bless you.. its work perfectly

Comment: Good Luck Kid!! God Bless you too:)

Comment: is there any way that i can use multiple variable  for example we have that  **$emails[]** and another varaible called **data[]** how can i pass both to my view ??

Answer (score 0):

Illegal offset type errors occur when you attempt to access an array index using an object or an array as the index key.

This question should about match your effort.